# Paypal API donations split to different business accounts

Tags: php, payment, paypal, donations

Hi is possible to split a paypal online donation to different paypal account letting user paying only 1 time?

i mean , user pays 30€ i would like to send 50% of them to 1 PP account and 50% to another PP account...

any idea guys? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use paypal's mass pay system after the payment has been made to the main account.  You can get the data in and out using the API.

**General overview docs:**
https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/mass_pay

**API docs:**
https://www.x.com/community/ppx/mass_pay

The trick in a system like this, is trying not to get soaked on fees, giving too much money to paypal.  Mass pay has no fees for the receiver, and low fees for the sender. Its also easy to process programatically.

The other way to do it would obviously be to just use the API and code it up to do the split and send the $ to each party using standard 'send a payment' though the API.  But you'll wind up giving a lot more money to paypal that way, mass pay is usually the better choice.

Comment: uhm need to doc about paypal mass pay :) thanks, anyway other solutions will be appreaciated :)

Comment: hey i  looked at docs :)) really usefull answer man thanks! :)